# getting a single index in an object to concatonate with an api call

Tags: javascript, api, object, intl

I'm trying to get a single index of daysArray to  concatonate with temperature.

Presently building a weather app and am trying to return an with the day of the week and the temperature. Right now it is returning the entire week and the temperature at the end. e.g `["Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "31.29"]`
`["Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "34.21"]`

What I'm looking to have appear is `["Friday","31.29"], ["Saturday","34.21"]`

I want to have then display in the li tags I've created below.

This is my code:

```
 const responseOne = await fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&exclude={current,minutely,hourly,alerts}&units=metric&appid=${apiKey}`)
        const dataOne = await responseOne.json()
        dataOne.daily.forEach(day => {
            
            function daysForLocale(localeName = 'en', weekday = 'long') {
                const format = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(localeName, { weekday }).format;
                const today = new Date();
                const daysArray = [...Array(8).keys()]
                  .map((val, index) => format(new Date(today.getTime() + 3600 * 24 * 1000 * (index))));
                  console.log(daysArray)
                    const temperature = JSON.stringify(day.temp.day)
                    console.log(daysArray)
                    const totDayTemp = daysArray.concat(temperature)
                    console.log(totDayTemp)               
                  return daysArray;
            }
            let tempDay = document.createElement('li')
            tempDay.innerText = `Daily Temperature: ${daysForLocale()} `
            tempDay.className = 'day'
            console.log(tempDay)
           return tempDay;
        })
```

Does anybody have an idea how I can get my desired output?

Response I'm getting is:

```
(8)[Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]
app.js:31 (8) ["Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]
app.js:33 (9) ["Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "30.04"]
app.js:39 <li class=​"day">​…​</li>​
app.js:29 (8) ["Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]
app.js:31 (8) ["Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]
app.js:33 (9) ["Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "25.83"]
app.js:39 <li class=​"day">​…​</li>​
app.js:29 (8) ["Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]
app.js:31 (8) ["Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]
app.js:33 (9) ["Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "26.72"]
```

[api call for dataOne](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHwU3.png)

JSON:

```
{
  "lat": 48.8534,
  "lon": 2.3488,
  "timezone": "Europe/Paris",
  "timezone_offset": 7200,
  "current": {
    "dt": 1629464870,
    "sunrise": 1629435036,
    "sunset": 1629485863,
    "temp": 23.23,
    "feels_like": 23.1,
    "pressure": 1017,
    "humidity": 57,
    "dew_point": 14.25,
    "uvi": 5.63,
    "clouds": 90,
    "visibility": 10000,
    "wind_speed": 2.06,
    "wind_deg": 0,
    "weather": [
      {
        "id": 804,
        "main": "Clouds",
        "description": "overcast clouds",
        "icon": "04d"
      }
    ]
  },
  "daily": [
    {
      "dt": 1629457200,
      "sunrise": 1629435036,
      "sunset": 1629485863,
      "moonrise": 1629484020,
      "moonset": 1629423780,
      "moon_phase": 0.43,
      "temp": {
        "day": 23.45,
        "min": 17.1,
        "max": 25.7,
        "night": 22.08,
        "eve": 25.7,
        "morn": 17.1
      },
      "feels_like": {
        "day": 23.23,
        "night": 21.75,
        "eve": 25.4,
        "morn": 16.75
      },
      "pressure": 1017,
      "humidity": 53,
      "dew_point": 13.33,
      "wind_speed": 2.65,
      "wind_deg": 57,
      "wind_gust": 5.74,
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 804,
          "main": "Clouds",
          "description": "overcast clouds",
          "icon": "04d"
        }
      ],
      "clouds": 90,
      "pop": 0.03,
      "uvi": 5.69
    },
    {
      "dt": 1629543600,
      "sunrise": 1629521521,
      "sunset": 1629572149,
      "moonrise": 1629572460,
      "moonset": 1629514740,
      "moon_phase": 0.46,
      "temp": {
        "day": 27.68,
        "min": 17.87,
        "max": 29.75,
        "night": 20.16,
        "eve": 24.18,
        "morn": 17.87
      },
      "feels_like": {
        "day": 27.46,
        "night": 20.09,
        "eve": 23.93,
        "morn": 17.57
      },
      "pressure": 1015,
      "humidity": 41,
      "dew_point": 13.21,
      "wind_speed": 6.08,
      "wind_deg": 253,
      "wind_gust": 8.33,
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 803,
          "main": "Clouds",
          "description": "broken clouds",
          "icon": "04d"
        }
      ],
      "clouds": 64,
      "pop": 0.04,
      "uvi": 5.7
    },
    {
      "dt": 1629630000,
      "sunrise": 1629608007,
      "sunset": 1629658434,
      "moonrise": 1629660420,
      "moonset": 1629605880,
      "moon_phase": 0.5,
      "temp": {
        "day": 22.32,
        "min": 16.19,
        "max": 23.79,
        "night": 18.41,
        "eve": 22.25,
        "morn": 16.68
      },
      "feels_like": {
        "day": 21.83,
        "night": 18.08,
        "eve": 21.81,
        "morn": 16.6
      },
      "pressure": 1020,
      "humidity": 47,
      "dew_point": 10.33,
      "wind_speed": 4.56,
      "wind_deg": 286,
      "wind_gust": 8.02,
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 500,
          "main": "Rain",
          "description": "light rain",
          "icon": "10d"
        }
      ],
      "clouds": 6,
      "pop": 0.88,
      "rain": 1.2,
      "uvi": 4.71
    },
    {
      "dt": 1629716400,
      "sunrise": 1629694492,
      "sunset": 1629744719,
      "moonrise": 1629748080,
      "moonset": 1629696960,
      "moon_phase": 0.53,
      "temp": {
        "day": 20.08,
        "min": 15.69,
        "max": 23.49,
        "night": 18.4,
        "eve": 20.66,
        "morn": 15.79
      },
      "feels_like": {
        "day": 20,
        "night": 18.33,
        "eve": 20.58,
        "morn": 15.75
      },
      "pressure": 1021,
      "humidity": 71,
      "dew_point": 14.42,
      "wind_speed": 4.15,
      "wind_deg": 40,
      "wind_gust": 9.46,
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 500,
          "main": "Rain",
          "description": "light rain",
          "icon": "10d"
        }
      ],
      "clouds": 100,
      "pop": 0.6,
      "rain": 1.19,
      "uvi": 4.54
    },
    {
      "dt": 1629802800,
      "sunrise": 1629780977,
      "sunset": 1629831002,
      "moonrise": 1629835560,
      "moonset": 1629787800,
      "moon_phase": 0.57,
      "temp": {
        "day": 20.92,
        "min": 14.77,
        "max": 21.51,
        "night": 17.83,
        "eve": 20.26,
        "morn": 14.77
      },
      "feels_like": {
        "day": 20.45,
        "night": 17.42,
        "eve": 19.88,
        "morn": 14.42
      },
      "pressure": 1023,
      "humidity": 53,
      "dew_point": 10.72,
      "wind_speed": 6.01,
      "wind_deg": 59,
      "wind_gust": 10.74,
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 802,
          "main": "Clouds",
          "description": "scattered clouds",
          "icon": "03d"
        }
      ],
      "clouds": 44,
      "pop": 0,
      "uvi": 3.37
    },
    {
      "dt": 1629889200,
      "sunrise": 1629867462,
      "sunset": 1629917285,
      "moonrise": 1629922920,
      "moonset": 1629878520,
      "moon_phase": 0.6,
      "temp": {
        "day": 22.48,
        "min": 14.08,
        "max": 23.49,
        "night": 17.61,
        "eve": 21.16,
        "morn": 14.08
      },
      "feels_like": {
        "day": 21.75,
        "night": 16.86,
        "eve": 20.4,
        "morn": 13.21
      },
      "pressure": 1020,
      "humidity": 37,
      "dew_point": 7.04,
      "wind_speed": 6.93,
      "wind_deg": 61,
      "wind_gust": 12.44,
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 800,
          "main": "Clear",
          "description": "clear sky",
          "icon": "01d"
        }
      ],
      "clouds": 1,
      "pop": 0,
      "uvi": 4
    },
    {
      "dt": 1629975600,
      "sunrise": 1629953948,
      "sunset": 1630003566,
      "moonrise": 1630010340,
      "moonset": 1629969060,
      "moon_phase": 0.63,
      "temp": {
        "day": 24.18,
        "min": 13.56,
        "max": 25.74,
        "night": 17.97,
        "eve": 23.21,
        "morn": 13.56
      },
      "feels_like": {
        "day": 23.59,
        "night": 17.31,
        "eve": 23.02,
        "morn": 12.69
      },
      "pressure": 1019,
      "humidity": 36,
      "dew_point": 8.14,
      "wind_speed": 4.96,
      "wind_deg": 16,
      "wind_gust": 10.09,
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 803,
          "main": "Clouds",
          "description": "broken clouds",
          "icon": "04d"
        }
      ],
      "clouds": 55,
      "pop": 0,
      "uvi": 4
    },
    {
      "dt": 1630062000,
      "sunrise": 1630040433,
      "sunset": 1630089847,
      "moonrise": 1630097820,
      "moonset": 1630059540,
      "moon_phase": 0.66,
      "temp": {
        "day": 24.02,
        "min": 14.63,
        "max": 24.72,
        "night": 18.37,
        "eve": 21.89,
        "morn": 14.87
      },
      "feels_like": {
        "day": 23.39,
        "night": 17.75,
        "eve": 21.23,
        "morn": 14.68
      },
      "pressure": 1021,
      "humidity": 35,
      "dew_point": 7.69,
      "wind_speed": 5.48,
      "wind_deg": 61,
      "wind_gust": 9.09,
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 800,
          "main": "Clear",
          "description": "clear sky",
          "icon": "01d"
        }
      ],
      "clouds": 1,
      "pop": 0,
      "uvi": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Instead of including the fetch operation, can you include the response object? That way we can run your code without apiKey (which I am not going to get).

Comment: Updated with response

Comment: I think you misunderstand. I am not asking for the console output, but the contents (in JSON format) of `dataOne`.

Comment: Apologies, ive updated with the output of dataOne

Comment: Please no screenshots. Also, that is console output format (which has many `...`). Please provide JSON format. You can produce JSON output with `console.log(JSON.stringify(dataOne, null, 2))`

Comment: sorry, JSON is added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues:

- Your code is looping over the `daily` array (having 8 entries) with `forEach`, but then you do a nested iteration with again 8 iterations, using `Array(8).keys()`. There is no need for a nested loop. You just need 8 results, not 8 * 8 results.
- The response has a `dt` member, which represents the date for which the weather conditions are given. So there is no need to fiddle around with `today.getTime()`. Just feed `dt*1000` to the Date constructor.
- You create `tempDay`, but then throw it away. Returning it in a `forEach` callback is useless, as `forEach` ignores any returned values.
- The `daysForLocale` would be better positioned outside the loop, provided you would pass it the arguments it needs.

Anyway I excluded the code that you use to create HTML elements, as I think it is not related to your question.

Here is code to generate the pairs of weekday and temperature:

```js
const dataOne = {
  "daily": [
    {"dt": 1629457200,"temp": {"day": 23.45}},
    {"dt": 1629543600,"temp": {"day": 27.68}},
    {"dt": 1629630000,"temp": {"day": 22.32}},
    {"dt": 1629716400,"temp": {"day": 20.08}},
    {"dt": 1629802800,"temp": {"day": 20.92}},
    {"dt": 1629889200,"temp": {"day": 22.48}},
    {"dt": 1629975600,"temp": {"day": 24.18}},
    {"dt": 1630062000,"temp": {"day": 24.02}}
  ]
};

const format = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { weekday: 'long' }).format;

const result = dataOne.daily.map(({dt, temp}) => [format(new Date(dt*1000)), temp.day]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, was so stumped.